# When speaking of vaccine efficacy (for COVID-19, or other), is immune response or efficacy really being measured?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, virus, immune-system, coronavirus

I've been performing many web searches using combinations of the words "vaccine", "vaccination", "COVID-19", "coronavirus", "efficacy", and "effectiveness", and have yet to find anything that provides an accurate answer to the following question:

When a vaccine manufacturer states that their vaccine is "95% effective", does that mean:

A. 100% of people receiving the vaccine during studies developed antibodies from the vaccine, but 5% still got sick.  (Which, I think, would actually mean it is less than "95% effective" because not everyone would get exposed to the virus that causes the illness.)

(or)

B. 95% (or less) of the study participants receiving the vaccine developed antibodies from the vaccine, therefore 5% of the people who received it still got sick.

Which is it (or is it something else), and if it is *"A"*, is my parenthetical understanding correct?

Although my interest lies predominantly regarding COVID-19 vaccines, I think this question is general enough that it could apply to any vaccination.

Comment: It means roughly "the likelihood that you get the virus is reduced by 95% relative to a control group that did not get the vaccine".

Comment: @BrenBarn Right, but why?  Reason A or B?  That is the question posed above.

Comment: It is about whether people contract the disease, not about antibodies.  See the duplicate question for more info.  But it is neither your A or B, because in both cases your description makes no reference to a control group.  The 95% number says nothing about 95% of people in the trial group.  It says the likelihood of getting the disease in the trial group is 95% *lower* than in the control group.  The proportion of people who got COVID in the vaccine trial was far lower than 5%.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks.  That makes sense and I think it reflects what I have read elsewhere (I'm very tired, so my brain needs rest right now).  I'm going to close my question and then after I have more time to think about it, write a question that more accurately asks what I'm trying to learn.  Thank you again for your help.